# How to M2MQTT Auto Reconnect

Tags: c#, asp.net, mqtt, paho, reconnect

i'm trying to use this protocol and already have 2 clients (one to publish and another to subscribe) and a broker working.

My question is i want to implement a reconnect feature in the subscribe client because the wifi signal is unstable and don't want to manually restart the client every single time, how can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the ConnectionClosed event to detect when a disconnect happens.

I then start a task that will try to reconnect the client.
Something like:

```
 private async Task TryReconnectAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var connected = _client.IsConnected;
        while (!connected && !cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                _client.Connect(_clientId);
            }
            catch
            {
                _logger.Log(LogLevel.Warn, "No connection to...{0}",_serverIp);
            }
            connected = _client.IsConnected;
            await Task.Delay(10000, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

Not perfect, but will do the job.

Comment: Inside the ConnectionClosed Event i have this,    
CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
Task T = Task.Run(() => TryReconnectAsync(source.Token));
T.Wait();  i dont know if it's the correct way, after the reconnect the sub stops receiving messages from the pub...

Comment: try subscribe to the topic again after the re-connection.

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for a simple connection persistence here is my solution used.

When you want to start your mqtt connection call `Task.Run(() => PersistConnectionAsync());` and note that `static bool _tryReconnectMQTT` should be defined at the class (or desired) scope level.

```
private async Task PersistConnectionAsync()
{
    var connected = _mqttClient.IsConnected;
    while (_tryReconnectMQTT)
    {
        if (!connected)
        {
            try
            {
                _mqttClient.Connect(_clientId);
            }
            catch
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("failed reconnect");
            }
        }
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        connected = _mqttClient.IsConnected;
    }
}
```

I would also suggest using the last will and testament to know how long your client was down for and when. Replace `_mqttClient.Connect(_clientId);` with the following.

```
_mqttClient.Connect(_clientId, 
            null, null,
            false,
            MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_AT_MOST_ONCE, //aws 
            true,
            $"/my/topic/{_clientId}connectionstatus",
            "{\"message\":\"disconnected\"}",
            true,
            60);
```

Publish a connected message to the same topic with similar message after the connection statement to ensure you know all the times you were disconnected. Using AWS rules engine you would be able to send a notification on connection status, it is even possible to notify yourself if the duration between the reconnect is over a certain time.

The m2mqtt client has a `.ConnectionClosed` event you can subscribe your reconnect method to.