# M2Mqtt reconnection doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, service, mqtt

I'm developping a linux service that implements a mqttclient to send informations of a automation devices to internet. This system will be in a location with poor internet so I need to handle disconnections and make sure it tries to make reconnections.

I read the post [How to M2MQTT Auto Reconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43547179/how-to-m2mqtt-auto-reconnect), and implemented this task in my system, but when I tested the reconnection the task didn't work. My Code:

```
public class Worker: IHostedService, IDisposable
{
       private readonly ILogger _logger;

       public Worker(ILogger<TimeHostedService> logger)
       {
           _logger = logger;
       }

       public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       {
             //Do other works
             Task.Run(() =>
             {
                 InitializeMqtt();
             )};

             return Task.CompletedTask;
       }

      private void InitializeMqtt()
      {
          mqttclient = new MqttClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["brokerip"]);
          Task.Run(() =>
          {
               MqttReconnection();
          )};
        
          mqttclient.MqttMsgPublishReceived += MqttSubscriber;
          mqttclient.Subscribe(new string[] { gwTopic + "/listencmd" }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_AT_LEAST_ONCE });
       }


      private async Task MqttReconnection()
      {
          var connected = mqttclient.IsConnected;
          while (true)
          {
            if(!connected)
            {
                try
                {
                    mqttclient.Connect(gwTopic, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["brokerUserName"],
                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["brokerPass"], true,MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_AT_LEAST_ONCE, true,
                        gwTopic + "/connectionstatus", "gw Disconnected", false, 3);
                    mqttclient.Publish(gwTopic + "/connectionstatus", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("gw Connected"), MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_AT_LEAST_ONCE, true);
                }
                catch
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Failed to reconnect broker");
                }
                await Task.Delay(10000);
                connected = mqttclient.IsConnected;
            }
        }
      }
}
```

If a have internet, i can connect with broker normally. if a Start a service without internet, the system tries to recconect. But when start the service with internet and simulate a disonnection, my service doesn't try to reconnect.

What i'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You set `connected` before starting the loop; so it's value will not change once it's `true` (the only place it could become `false` is protected by `if(!connected)`). Moving `var connected...` into the `while` should address this. However this may not be the [recommended approach](https://github.com/dotnet/MQTTnet/blob/master/Samples/Client/Client_Connection_Samples.cs#L393) and is a very tight loop when the connection is up (so will waste CPU resource).